# Acumatica: Issue inserting POLine from another Graph

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a custom graph based on a custom `DAC`, and in a `fieldUpdated` event on this graph I am inserting a `POLine`.  The insert works fine and the line appears on the `PO`, but the `PO` Header Line Total does not update and no `PlanID` is assigned to the `PO` Line.  When a `PO` Line is manually entered on the `PO` Order Entry screen, the `PlanID` and Header Line Total value is assigned/updated by the graph.

My (summarized) code is as follows:

```cs
public SelectFrom<POOrder>.View POView;
public SelectFrom<POLine>
      .Where<POLine.pONbr.IsEqual<
     POOrder.orderNbr.FromCurrent>>
     .View POLineView;

protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PSCHOrder, PSCHOrder.pOOrderNbr> e)
        {

            if (e.NewValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)e.NewValue))
            {

                var sorder = PXSelect<POOrder, Where<POOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(this, e.NewValue);
                POView.Current = sorder;

                var line = new POLine();
                line.OrderNbr = e.NewValue;
                line.OrderQty = 1;
                line.TranDesc = "my desc";
                line.InventoryID = id; //code to lookup id not shown
                //Assign Some Custom Fields
                PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(line).UsrDoorCD = "xxx";
                PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(line).UsrDoorPoNbr = "yyy"
                PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(line).UsrJobName = "abc";
                //Insert Line
                savedLine = this.POLineView.Insert(line);

            }
}
```

Is this an incorrect design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these fields (lineTotal or PlanID) calculate automatically.  You will need to update.  Otherwise, the best way to do this would be to create a graph instance of POOrderEntry and insert the line through that graph's view.  It is not considered good practice to create a graph instance in an event handler however.

```
POOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POOrderEntry>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Patrick.  I had worked around the issue by moving my logic to an action where I can instantiate the PXGraph instead of trying to insert the lines from an event, where like you said, it's not good practice to create a graph instance.

Comment: you could also move the code to persist in your custom graph and do all changes when the user saves to the POOrderEntry graph

Comment: @Brendan thanks for the suggestion.  I had implemented my own Save action so I could run the code from there, but persist looks like a better option.